# Xcode uiscrollview shows up behind nav bar in IB

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

Trying to set up a scrollview in a UIViewController that has a nav bar. In IB my content gets pushed up to the top below the nav bar (see image).

When running the app on my phone the view is pushed down to sit below the nav bar which is fine. Is there anyway to get it to reflect like this in IB. It is hard to set up my content when half of it is cut off.

If I add a constraint to make the top of the view sit below the nav bar when I run the app it adds that offset and doesn't look correct. (I guess I could alter the constraint before running on my phone but seems like a ridiculous hack just to layout my app).  (Already having major issues getting my scrollView to work the way I want it to... don't scroll if my content fits the screen but also use the scroll view to move the view up if the content is covered up by the keyboard but thats for another post)

[image]

when I run in simulator looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder you should make sure your NavigationBar is set to Opaque in the simulated metrics.  When you have a transparent Nav bar content can go underneath it.

It might look right in your app if you have a global attribute applied to make sure all nav bars are not translucent.

[image]

Comment: You can also programmatically do that by using 'setContentInset:' and 'setScrollIndicatorInsets:' on a UIScrollView or UITableView if you're using one